# Accessing office project classes from windows form application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, vsto

I am creating an management project that take some inputs from user and then print them after proper formatting

I've created 2 projects

1. windows form application (for taking input in strings n datagridview )
2. office project (for formatting and printing data of my first project)

I have imported the office project and its .dll files to my 1st project
but the question is how to pass parameters(string n datagridview) to thisdocument class of office project It already have some parameters and I don't know how to pass its built-in and new parameter from 1st project

```
private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
dataGridView.Rows.Add("1", "a", "1", "1"); 
dataGridView.Rows.Add("2", "b", "2", "2"); 
dataGridView.Rows.Add("3", "c", "3", "3"); 
WordDocumentProject.ThisDocument = new ThisDocument(); 
}
```

Comment: I asked a while ago if you could show us some of your code to better illustrate the question, this is a very active site so when you ask a question try and stay around for a bit. Good luck!

Comment: //thisDocument(2nd project (office) class)'s constructor
public ThisDocument(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Factory factory, global::System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider):base(factory, serviceProvider, "ThisDocument", "ThisDocument") 
{
            Globals.Factory = factory;
}

Comment: //1st project(winForm) data 
 private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("1", "a", "1", "1");
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("2", "b", "2", "2");
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("3", "c", "3", "3");
//here is error how to pass the parameter of thisdocument constuctor(given above in comment)  
            WordDocumentProject.ThisDocument TDObj= new ThisDocument(               
}

Comment: Please dont use comments to post code, please edit your question like I showed you :) Feel free to comment on my answer if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Its all documented, here is a great example: [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384)

So to pass the strings in the datagridview to word to print you do it like this:

```
//Start Word and create a new document.
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

//Insert a datagridview info into the document.
DataTable dt = (DataTable)datagridview1.DataSource;
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
Word.Paragraph oPara1;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
oPara1.Range.Text = dr[0].ToString();
oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;    //24 pt spacing after paragraph.
oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```